# Effective method for Date.parse in javascript

Tags: javascript

In a method, i am using Date.parse to convert the date to millisecond as below.

```
 Date.parse(Tue Apr 1 00:00:00 PST 1930);
```

but i am using it for 1000 points , so the execution time for Date.parse is 60ms(shown in profiler), i need to optimize it, is there any other way to do it or Date.parse is the only way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't think of any other way of generating a `Date` from a `string` in JS. Where do you get the date strings from? Perhaps you could manipulate the output to be less verbose which should reduce the parsing time.

Comment: `new Date("Tue Apr 1 00:00:00 PST 1930").getTime()` could be an alternative, but not sure about its performance.

Comment: @Nikhil `new Date(...)` is the equivalent of `Date.parse(...)` so I can't imagine the performance will be any different.

Comment: @James then I also can't think of any other alternative for now.

Answer (score 0):

Even custom parser of a predefined date's format is slower then direct date parsing: [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/date-parse-vs-custom-parser). May be you know what in a custom parser could be eliminated, or to try to get rid of the `.split` function by storing your dates direct in JSON format like `{year:2013, date:1, month:11, hour: 11}`.